# Woocommerce, how to change the stock on product to percentage bar?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Below is an example of what I mean, but how would this be done with woocommerce?

```
    // Testing numbers. Replace with your own.
$value = 40;
$max = 150;
$scale = 1.0;

// Get Percentage out of 100
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; } 
else { $percent = 0; }


// Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
if ( $percent > 100 ) { $percent = 100; }

The CSS
    .percentbar { background:#CCCCCC; border:1px solid #666666; height:10px; }
.percentbar div { background: #28B8C0; height: 10px; }

The HTML
    <div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px;">
    <div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;"></div>
</div>
Percentage: <?php echo $percent; ?>%
```

But how would it be done with woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

By default woocommerce doesn't keep how much stock you had in the beginning, each order decrements the stock by that amount. However, it does keep a track of how much stock there currently are and how much has been sold. Combining the two of them will tell you how much stock in total there is. From that, using your example code above I put the below together.

```
<?php
    $max = get_post_meta($product->id, 'total_sales', true) + $product->get_stock_quantity();;
    $value = get_post_meta($product->id, 'total_sales', true);
    $scale = 1.0;

    // Get Percentage out of 100
    if ( !empty($max) )
    {
        $percent = ($value * 100) / $max;
    }
    else
    {
        $percent = 0;
    }

    // Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
    if ($percent > 100 )
    {
        $percent = 100;
    }
?>

<div class="percentbar" style="background:#CCCCCC; border:1px solid #666666; height:10px; width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px;">
<div style="background: #28B8C0; height: 10px; width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;"></div>
Percentage: <?php echo $percent; ?>%
```

I am assuming this is going to be displayed instead of the `X in stock` text. So in "woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php"* replace the following line of code with the above:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
```

You can modify "simple.php" itself, but that will get overridden if you ever update woocommerce. It is [recommended](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) that you

> Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure.